# Is Output Cell Size Environment the same as Resample tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, resampling, grids-sum

I have a raster catalog that contains hundreds of rasters (10 x 10). I need to perform Cell Statistics SUM on all the raster. End user able to specify under what cell size the want to perform the operation (ex: 50 x 50).

**I want to find out if the following two scenario is actually the same**?

1st: Set the CELLSIZE Environment variable of Cell Statistics tool to 50 x 50 and perform cell statistics SUM.

2nd: For each of the raster, run Resample (type: NEAREST) tool to resize to 50 x 50 and run cell statistics SUM on all the rasters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Final result generated will be a bit different but performance on 2nd will definitely be slower than 1st.

Comment: what would be the difference between both?